# Segmentation fault in a linked list using classes. Am I doing the method correctly?

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I need to do a linked list using classes. I was debugging and I can't seem to fix the segmantation fault.

Does this have something to do with the use of classes? Previously I only used structs but per instructions I'm not able to at the moment. Or am I missing something in my code? Am I missing something in the constructor?

I left comments of where in the code I get the segmenation error.

palabra.h file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Palabra{
public:
    int p_id;
    string p_nombre;
    int p_valor;

    Palabra *next;
    Palabra *prev;

//Metodos
    Palabra(int id, string nombre);
    void printNombre();
    int calcularValorPalabra();

    void agregarSiguiente(Palabra *);
    void eliminar();
    void buscar();
};

extern Palabra primeraPalabra;
extern Palabra ultimaPalabra;
extern Palabra palabraTemp;
```

Palabra.cpp file

```
Palabra primeraPalabra(0,"");
Palabra ultimaPalabra(0, "");
Palabra palabraTemp(0, "");


Palabra::Palabra(int id, string nombre)
    {
        p_id = id;
        p_nombre = nombre;
        p_valor = calcularValorPalabra();

        next = NULL;
        prev = NULL;
    }


void Palabra::agregarSiguiente(Palabra *nuevaPalabra)
{
    palabraTemp = primeraPalabra;

    if(primeraPalabra.p_nombre == "") //I assing the first node of the linked list, I check if the Name is empty
    {
        primeraPalabra = *nuevaPalabra;
        ultimaPalabra = *nuevaPalabra;
    }
    else while (&palabraTemp != NULL)
    {

        if(palabraTemp.next == NULL)
        {
            palabraTemp.next = nuevaPalabra; //Right here I get the error when debugging. 
            break;
        }
        palabraTemp = *palabraTemp.next;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main()
{

    Palabra prototypo(1,"proto");
    Palabra prototypo1(2,"proto2");

    primeraPalabra.agregarSiguiente(&prototypo);
    cout << primeraPalabra.p_nombre;
    primeraPalabra.agregarSiguiente(&prototypo1);
    cout << primeraPalabra.next->p_nombre;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `palabraTemp = primeraPalabra` creates a copy of the entire `primeraPalabra` object? You should probably take its address  instead and work with pointers. Likewise, note that `&palabraTemp` will NEVER be NULL. I suggest you re-read your textbook regarding pointers. Finally, please show a [mcve] (including calling code)

Comment: Thanks for that information Botje. I can see that now. I'm definitely gonna correct that, regarding the copy of the object. I will work with the addresses of the objects instead. And yes, I was debugging and noticed that it will never be NULL. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: I apologize here, normally reading linked list classes is hard for me because there's a lot of pointers being thrown around, but here there's also the extra work required to translate each function name from spanish to english. I see that "palabra" means word - is it also synonymous with "node"?

Comment: Sure no problem. Can you explain the issue? I was able to get the code to run, seems like Botje said, I was not using correctly the pointers. I do believe I was working with the classes.

Comment: Palabra should not also be a node. A Palabra is one thing, and a node is a distinct, other thing.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that in this code block you might end up dereferencing a null pointer!

```cpp
if(palabraTemp.next == NULL)
{
  palabraTemp.next = nuevaPalabra; //Right here I get the error when debugging. 
  break;
}
palabraTemp = *palabraTemp.next;
```

If your variable `palabraTemp.next` is `NULL`, then the instruction `*palabraTemp.next` is buggy

Comment: That's what I was thinking. In this case, since palabraTemp.next = NULL. I tried assigning palabraTemp.next = address of pointer. But it doesn't work.

Comment: what's in your method `int Palabra::calcularValorPalabra()` ?

Comment: It's method to assign a value to Palabra.valor. I was able to get the code to run with the correct use of pointers as Botje suggested on the comments. +1 for the help. palabra.next was definitely buggy but it was because I was not using the pointers correctly.